# How to display user nickname (not display name) in PHP template?

Tags: php, templates, user-meta, username

I would like to display a nickname instead of username/display name on top of my website. I want to insert PHP codes which can display that Nickname in a PHP page. I have tried these codes below, but they don't work:

```
........some codes above...................
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>

{if is_user_logged_in()}
    <?php
        $nickname = $current_user->user_nickName;
    ?>

    <?php echo $nickname; ?>
    ..........some codes below.........
```

But it works for username as below:

```
........some codes above...................
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>

{if is_user_logged_in()}
    <?php
        $username = $current_user->user_login;
    ?>

    <?php echo $username; ?>
    ..........some codes below.........
```

Any suggestion is very appreciated!

Comment: edit your question to explain how you create the nickname.

Comment: The user nickname is part of core WP.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `$current_user` object doesn't have a property called `user_nickName` because the user nickname is stored in the user meta.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
$nickname = $meta->nickname;
```

Or

```
$nickname = get_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'nickname', true );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working now with my above codes this is because i was stupid to update the file on the main theme; not the child theme.

Comment: here is the working code: <?php global $current_user;
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>
              
        {if is_user_logged_in()}
  
     <?php $my_display_name = $current_user->nickname;  ?> which i can now use that variable $my_display_name to display

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan Johnson. I have tried it and it works well.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/224882)

Comment: You can also upvote to show your thanks